# Assistance requested on optimal placement for notification system and naming of rule for orchestrating transactions

Tags: middleware, soa, messagebroker, event-driven, orchestration

I have two queries that I need your assistance with.

Firstly, I would like to know the optimal placement for the notification system, specifically in the context of enterprise applications such as banking environments, and whether it is best situated at the MW IBM Broker for the orchestration or at the event source system.

In my opinion, the event source system should serve as the trigger for the notification system. In the event of a failure, we can then reverse the transaction.

My second query relates to the naming of the rule for orchestrating transactions. Should it be located at the IBM Broker as an Orchestrator or at the backend source to control the flow of transactions? Can you provide guidance on when each approach is suitable and the relevant topic name?

I suggest utilizing the IBM Broker as an orchestrator when the required services are related to the necessary business services or validation. If there is no relation, then the backend should control the flow for those services.

I hope my queries are clear, and I would appreciate your response.